# Android App Determining Location Name

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm pretty new to Android App development in general, and haven't done hardly anything with GPS usage in apps, so I have a question if something is possible before I attempt it. Hoping someone could point me towards some resources if possible.

In my app I'd like to be looking at the user's location whenever it changes, and get the name of the location is possible. When I say name, I don't mean the address I mean something like Walmart or McDonald's, etc. Would the Google Maps API allow me to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the idea is: 
1- If you want to always know the user location, you need to subscribe for Location changes notifications. 
2- Once you have the Location object, you can use the Geocoder class and get the address using getFromLocation method. 
3- On second step you will receive a List and the Address class have a getFeatureName() method, that will return what you need.